# I can't understand SOME, NONE, isSome in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I can't understand SOME, NONE, isSome in sml
As i know, each p1,p2...pn is constructor.

```
case e0 of
 p1 => e1
 p1 => e1
|p2 => e2 
 …
|pn => en
```

but when we denote

`datatype 'a option = NONE | SOME of 'a`

professor said NONE is not constructor but just subtype of 'a option
I can't understand why it is.

Also i have an error like this

```
 isSome NONE;    

 stdIn:1.2-23.4 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]                                                           
 operator domain: 'Z ?.Assembly.option
```

Am i wrong?

Comment: I think your professor is either confused or unclear. `NONE` is a constructor, not a type, and SML does not have subtypes in the normal sense of the word.

Answer (score 2):

> `NONE` is not constructor but just subtype of `'a option`

I had not thought that it is wrong to say that `NONE` is a value/pattern constructor of the type `'a option`. I'm not sure what your professor is aiming to say, but perhaps it is that `'a option` is actually a family/collection of types. `NONE` is a value/pattern constructor of every type `'a option` for concrete values of `'a`, but since `NONE : 'a option`, even though it doesn't take any *value* parameters, it does take a *type* parameter (e.g. `int` for `int option`), making its [*kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) higher.

Standard ML doesn't have a syntax for describing the kind of a type operator like `option`, but in Haskell we'd say that `option` has kind `* -> *` and `int option` has kind `*`. Going back to `NONE : 'a option`, you can concretize *what* it's none of to get what would unambiguously be a value/pattern constructor of a single type.

This is if you're into type theory. A simpler and less precise view is that *{ `NONE` }* is a subset of values of type `'a option`, and that this subset is equivalent in structure to the `unit` type, *{ `()` }*. But `NONE`, as an element of that subset, is not a subtype, or a type at all. It is a *value* and a *pattern* constructor depending on where you use it:

```
fun isSome NONE = false
  | isSome (SOME _) = true
```

Here, `NONE` is used in a pattern.

```
fun map f NONE = NONE
  | map f (SOME x) = SOME (f x)
```

Here, `NONE` is used in a pattern on the left-hand side and as a value on the right-hand side.

Perhaps someone with more experience in type theory can correct me.

> ```
> - isSome NONE;    
> stdIn:1.2-23.4 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
> ```

This looks like you have two conflicting definitions of `'a option`, one that you made yourself and one from the standard library. The standard library functions like `isSome` work only on the type defined by the standard library, so if you declare your own `datatype 'a option = NONE | SOME of 'a` for demonstrative purposes, that definition will actually conflict with and consequently shadow the built-in one, making all the standard library functions that refer to it less useful, since you can't create or pattern match against values directly with `NONE` and `SOME ...`, or type-annotate with `: ... option`.